# Login with VB.Net and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, authentication

I am a begginer with VB.Net and SQL Server and i want to do a Login sequence. What have in mind to me validate the user and password with SELECT COUNT but i can't put two conditions (User and Password). My Login Function is:

```
      Public Function Login(ByVal User As String, ByVal Pass As String) As Integer
    Dim query1 As String = ""
    Dim num1 As Integer        
    query1 = "Select Count(Us_User) from SC_User Where Us_User='" & User & "'" In this line i want to count the two things.        
    num1 = Access.LoadQuery(query1)
    Return num1
End Function
```

Thanks in advance. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
query1 = "Select Count(Us_User) from SC_User Where Us_User='" & User & "' and Password='" & Pass  &"'"
```